# Creating a cache-friendly component system

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic, entity-component-system

I am fairly new to c++ and am attempting to write a simple 2D game engine. I am currently working on my object model: a pure component system, similar to that described in the Data Locality chapter in [Game Programming Patterns](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html), whereby the components are fixed types, each stored in a separate array in the game world class. My current code looks a bit like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define SID(str) HashString(str)

typedef unsigned long long StringID;

// Simple FNV string hash.
StringID HashString(const char* str) {
    const unsigned int fnv_prime = 0x811C9DC5;
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int len = strlen(str);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        hash *= fnv_prime;
        hash ^= (str[i]);
    }

    return hash;
}

// Component base class
class Component
{
public:
    static const int    MAX_COMPONENTS = 10;

    Component()         {};
    virtual             ~Component() {};

    virtual void        Update() = 0;

    StringID            mID;
};

// Basic 2D vector.
struct Vec2 {
    float x;
    float y;
};

// Component for storing world position.
class TransformComponent : public Component
{
public:
                        TransformComponent() {}

                        TransformComponent(float x, float y) {
                            Vec2 mPosition = { x, y };
                        }

    virtual             ~TransformComponent() {};

    virtual void        Update() { /* No need to update- only to store data */ };

private:
    Vec2                mPosition;
};

// A struct for storing components in a contiguous way.
struct Components
{
    int CurrentTransformComponents = 0;
    TransformComponent* TransformComponents = new TransformComponent[Component::MAX_COMPONENTS];
};

// Variarg function to add all listed components
template <typename T>
inline void AddComponents(StringID gameObjectID, T component) {
    Application* app = Application::GetApplication();

    std::cout << "Adding component..." << std::endl;
    // Ugly placement of componet in array :)
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(TransformComponent)) {
        component.mID = gameObjectID;
        // Add component to the correct place in the array;
        app->mComponents.TransformComponents[app->mComponents.CurrentTransformComponents] = component;
        ++app->mComponents.CurrentTransformComponents;
    }
}

template <typename Arg, typename ... Args>
inline void AddComponents(StringID gameObjectID, Arg first, Args ... args) {
    AddComponents(gameObjectID, first);
    AddComponents(gameObjectID, args...);
}

// Adds componets AND returns ID.
template <typename ... Args>
inline StringID CreateGameObject(const char* name, Args ... args) {
    std::cout << "Creating GameObject " << name << " ";
    StringID id = SID((char*)name);
    std::cout << "Hash ID is " << id << std::endl;
    AddComponents(id, args...);
    return id;
}

// A base app class. 
// This is a singleton :(
class Application
{
    template <typename T>
    friend void AddComponents(StringID gameObjectID, T component);

public:
                        Application() : mComponents() {
                            if (mApplication != nullptr) {
                                std::cout << "Application already exists. You can only create 1 Application" << std::endl;
                            }
                            mApplication = this;
                        }

    virtual             ~Application() {}

    static Application* GetApplication() { return mApplication; }

    // Debug run to check components have been added correctly.
    void                Run() {
                            StringID testObject1ID = CreateGameObject("testObject1", TransformComponent(0, 0));
                            StringID testObject2ID = CreateGameObject("testObject2", TransformComponent(0, 0), TransformComponent(10, 10));

                            std::cin.get();
                        }
private:
    Components          mComponents;

    static Application* mApplication;
};

Application* Application::mApplication = nullptr;

class TestGame : public Application {

};

int main() {
    TestGame* testGame = new TestGame();
    testGame->Run();

    delete testGame;
    return 0;
}
```

## Pros:

- It is cache-friendly
- It is relatively flexible

## Cons:

- Template functions are slow
- The repeated `typeid` is very bad :)

I don't know if using variarg templates is the best option, because it means i have to use all of those `typeid`s. Also, I feel like the variarg template functions aren't the best either, however the only alternatives I can think of are functions for each component, eg.

```cpp
void AddTransformComponent(StringID gameObjectID, TransformComponent component);
```

or overloaded functions, such as

```cpp
void AddComponent(StringID gameObjectID, TransformComponent component);
```

If there is any code which you need which is missing, please say.

Thanks for the help, and i would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Oh, there is code that is missing... what happened to `//Data...` or `/* Data args... */`? Can't I read `c++` or have you removed anything? On Code Review you need to post complete code.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have now edited the code and it compiles correctly on Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Great! I now voted to reopen it. Could you tell us one more thing, which c++ version this is targetting?

Comment: I am currently targeting C++17. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I don’t have time to write a full answer, but what is the point of the `Application` class? This construct looks like a way to try to legitimize global variables. Why not put the code in `Run` in `main` or at least a free function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: I first looked at modernizing your code, after that, I've resolved your questions in the assumption you applied my suggestions.

Looking at your code, I'm a bit worried that you are trying to reeinvent some weels. First of all: `SID` and `HashString`.

I'm really worried about this, as it ain't as readable, predictable and performant as it could be.

Let's start with readable: Why would you redefine `HashString` to `SID`? This introduces an extra indirection that doesn't add any value. I can see some arguments of making an alias, however, as you are using C++17, just make it an inline function.

Secondly: Predictable. HashString returns a `StringId`. All `std::hash` return `std::size_t`. I suspect it's the same type, however, all your calculations use `unsigned int` instead of `StringId`. So any hash you create will have several zeros.

Finally: Performance. Your function accepts `const char *`. Why don't you use `std::string_view` instead? If you would have a `std::string`, it already knows the size, so you shouldn't recalculate it. It can still be called with a zero-terminated char*, in which case strlen will be called in the Ctor of the view.

As already said, it looks like a reimplementation of `std::hash<std::string_view>`. However, I see an argument in having your own hash function.

Still looking at the same function: `fnv_prime` is a constant. Why don't you use `constexpr` for it instead of `const`?

I also see a for-loop. Whenever, I see `for (i = 0`, I immediately worry about the scope of the variable, do we need it after the loop? Having to check this increases the complexity for me. How about `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; ++i)`? However, as you will be using `std::string_view`, it can become: `for (auto c : str)`, even easier to read/understand;

Moving on: the Component class. Again, you have a constant that could be constexpr. However, I'm worried much more about `mID`. This ID is free to access for everyone and free to update. Make it private and provide a getter/setter for it.

Your constructor/dtor are implemented as `{}`, while this could be `= default;` and the move/copy ctor/assignment are missing. Best to check on `the rule of 5`.

Going forward: TransformComponent. Are you compiling with compiler warnings (`-Weverything -Werror` in Clang, `/WX /W4` in MSVC)? You have a nice example of what is called shadowing. The member `mPosition` will never be initialized as you create a variable with the same name in a different scope. One could even wonder why you pass `x` and `y` separately, I would expect a single argument of type `Vec2`.

The struct `Components` creeps me out. Looking at it, its a really bad implementation of `std::vector`. Get rid of it! (And prereserve the vector if relevant).

`AddComponents` also looks pre-C++17. An alternative:

```
template <typename Arg, typename ... Args>
inline void AddComponents(StringID gameObjectID, Arg first, Args ... args) {
    // Do the work
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args))
        AddComponents(gameObjectID, args...);
}
```

Moving to `CreateGameObject` why do a c-style cast to `char*` when not needed?

Up to the `Application` class. This looks like an attempt for a singleton pattern. I would at least use `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout` for reporting failures. However, I'd even recommend `assert`. Your destructor also never resets the static to  `nullptr`.

And a final remark for `main`: Why would you even allocate memory here. Try writing it as:

```
TestGame testGame{};
testGame.Run();
return 0;
```

Looking at your questions:

**Templates ain't slow**, please compile with optimizations: `-O3` in clang, `/O2` in MSVC. It might hurt you for compile time, however, it hurts less as having to write everything manually.

I agree, `typeid` is bad. You don't need it. Having the overload will work good enough without the runtime overhead. However, I wouldn't overload `AddComponents` on the type. I would have an overloaded function that returns you the correct `std::vector`. Much less code to duplicate, much easier to reuse at other places.

```
template<typename T>
auto &getStorage()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, TransformComponent>)
        return TransformComponents;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, OtherComponent>)
        return OtherComponents;
}
template<typename T>
const auto &getStorage() const
{
     return const_cast<ThisType &>(*this).getStorage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Just one quick question. How would the overloaded function returning the vector be implemented? What would its declaration look like?

Comment: I've added a possible implementation.
Another could be by having a templated function and specialized functions that return the right vector. As your example only contains a single type, its a bit hard to know how you are currently intending to store it.

Comment: It took me a while to figure this out: “iso” = “instead of”. Your answer would benefit if you wrote that out.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've updated it, thanks for the input